# post big data via Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl

Tags: php, zend-framework, post, zend-http-client

I use  `$site->setParameterPost` and `$site->request('POST')->getBody()` for posting data to an action, one parameter of `setParameterPost` is very big data, and it doesn't send data via post method. What can I do?

```
 $config = array('adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl' );

 $site = new Zend_Http_Client('http://somewhere.tld/api/news', $config);
 $site->setParameterPost(array(
        'news' => $news, //very big data, without it data send properly
        'modelName' => 'somemodel',
        'method' => 'somemethod',
        'key' => 'something',
        'siteName' => $sitename,
            ));

$sitedata = $site->request('POST')->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use streaming requests, which are allowed only with PUT method.

```
$http_client = new Zend_Http_Client ('http://something.some/thing');
$http_client->setConfig (array (
    'adapter' => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
    'timeout' => 180
));

$file = fopen ('news.dat', 'r'); // put all your news to the file beforehand
$http_client->setRawData ($file);
$http_client->setParameterPost (array (
    'modelName' => 'somemodel',
    'method' => 'somemethod',
    'key' => 'something',
    'siteName' => $sitename
));
$response = $http_client->request ('PUT');
```

On the server-side you can access your big data through

```
fopen ("php://input", "r");
```